# Adding multiple QDockWidget's

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am able to add QDockWidgets as follows:

```
QDW1 QDW2;
QDW3 QDW4;
```

by using the code

```
QDockWidget *dwidget = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW1"), this);
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dwidget);
dwidget = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW2"), this);
dwidget->show();
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dwidget);

QDockWidget *dwidget2 = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW2"), this);
addDockWidget(Qt::RighttDockWidgetArea, dwidget2);
dwidget2 = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW4"), this);
dwidget2->show();
addDockWidget(Qt::RighttDockWidgetArea, dwidget2);
```

Now I want to add as follows:

I want to add total of 6 QDockWidgets

```
QDW1 QDW2 QDW3;
QDW4 QDW5 QDW6;
```

Can you please give me an idea how to add the dock widgets in this 2X3 format?

Thank you for the help.

HBS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
QDockWidget *dwidget = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW1"), this);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dwidget);
QDockWidget *dwidget2 = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW2"), this);
splitDockWidget(dwidget, dwidget2, Qt::Horizontal);

QDockWidget *dwidget3 = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW3"), this);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dwidget3);
QDockWidget *dwidget4 = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW4"), this);
splitDockWidget(dwidget3, dwidget4, Qt::Horizontal);

QDockWidget *dwidget5 = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW5"), this);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dwidget5);
QDockWidget *dwidget6 = new QDockWidget(tr("QDW6"), this);
splitDockWidget(dwidget5, dwidget6, Qt::Horizontal);
```

Comment: Simpsons,

That helped me to align the widgets in the way i want, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty easy answer, maybe I am missing something - couldn't you just add three each to the top and bottom DockWidgetArea?
How does your main widget / layout look like? Usually dockWidgets are not intended as the sole content, no?